# After swiftui’s tabview switched to the specified page, how the network requests once?

Tags: swiftui

After swiftui’s tabview is switched to the specified page, the network requests once, and there is no need to initiate the request next time. Every time the request occurs when switching to the specified page, it is too performance-consuming, but swiftui has onAppear and onDisappear two methods, how to implement it only A network request?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTGMO.png)

Comment: Please don't use images of code. Paste it into your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network code should be in a separate class object that you use as a model. You probably only want one instance of that object and that should take care of your issue making multiple connections.
Your model class can then be observable and provide the items your view needs to display status such as

```
@Published var inProgress = false
@Published var statusCode = 0
```

Your view can use onReceive to watch statusCode for changes and update itself accordingly.